# php code to a class?

Tags: php, database, class

How can I put those two code snippets in a class so the databasehandling is in a class? Like a PDO connection or put all that have to do with database is in a class, how would you guys do it?

Here are two parts of the code from different files. I am trying to develop a blog application.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("blogg1")or die(mysql_error()); 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$title = $_POST["title"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$content = $_POST ["content"];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO blogdata(title , category , content) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$content')");  
}else{
?>



<?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("blogg1")or die(mysql_error());
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogdata ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $title = $row["title"];
        $category = $row["category"];
        $content = $row["content"];


        ?>

        <table border = "1">
        <tr><td><?php echo $title; ?></td><td><?php echo $category; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $content; ?></td></tr>
    </table>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Nothing so extravagant, what exactly what do you wonder

Comment: Here you go >>> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: You should definitely use PDO instead of mysql_* functions as the mysql_* functions have been deprecated

Comment: As Patrick stated, don't use those old functions. Plus, it will only defeat the purpose of using your present code in a class. It's kind of like trying to use Diesel fuel in a Ferrari ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should keep your database credentials in a separate PHP file in a folder not accessible by the web, for example ~/lib/db.php

```
<?php
    define('SQL_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('SQL_DATABASE', 'your-db-name');
    define('SQL_USER', 'your-db-user');
    define('SQL_PASS', 'your-db-password');
?>
```

Then your Database class (also in ~/lib):

```
<?php
    require_once('~/lib/db.php');
    require_once('~/lib/BlogData.php');
    class Database
    {
        protected $db = null;

        function __construct()
        {
            // db connection options
            $driverOptions = array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false
            );

           // set new connection
           $this->db = PDO(
               "mysql:dbname=".SQL_DATABASE.";host=".SQL_HOST,
               SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, $driverOptions
           );               
        }

        // This function lets you fetch blog data using any sort order you'd like and any WHERE criteria you want
        function getBlogData($where = "1", $orderBy = "id DESC")
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
                SELECT * 
                FROM {'blogdata'} WHERE $where
                ORDER BY $orderBy
            ");
            $blogData = Array();
            if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $oneBlogData = new BlogData($this);
                    $oneBlogData->init($row);
                    $blogData[] = $oneBlogData;
                }
            }
            return $blogData;
        }

        function insertBlogData(BlogData $blogData)
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
                INSERT INTO {'blogdata'} (title , category , content) VALUES
                (:title, :category, :content);
            ");

            $stmt->bindParam(':title', $blogData->title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':category', $blogData->category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':content', $blogData->content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();  
        }
    }
?>
```

Then I would define another class for your blog data:

```
<?php
    class BlogData {
        public $title;
        public $category;
        public $content;
        private $db;

        function __construct(Database $db)
        {
            $this->db = $db;
        }
        function init($dbRow)
        {
            $this->title = $dbRow['title'];
            $this->category = $dbRow['category'];
            $this->content = $dbRow['content'];
        }
        function save()
        {
           // TODO: Write sql statement to save the row...
        }
    }
?>
```

Then your first block of code could create a new BlogData entry like this:

```
<?php
    require_once('~/lib/Database.php');
    $db = new Database();
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $blogData = new BlogData($db);
        $blogData->title = $_POST["title"];
        $blogData->category = $_POST["category"];
        $blogData->content = $_POST["content"];
        $db->insertBlogData($blogData);
    }
?>
```

And your second block of code could look like this:

```
<?php
    require_once('~/lib/Database.php');
    $db = new Database();
    $blogDataArray = $db->getBlogData("1", "id DESC");
    echo "<table border = '1'>";
    foreach($blogDataArray as $blogData)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $blogData->title . "</td><td>" . $blogData->category . "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" . $blogData->content . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

This also makes it really easy to modify BlogData entries - just fetch the blog data from the Database using the getBlogData function, modify the object by simply changing it's values and calling save. For example:

```
<?php
    // ... 
    $newContent = "New Content";
    $blogData = $db->getBlogData("id='1'");
    $blogData->content = $newContent;
    $blogData->save();
?>
```

I should also point out the obvious that you need some unique field for your blog data entries. With some id, it'd be easier to write addToDatabase and save in one function.

Comment: Even though you spent a lot of time posting this answer, it's sadly outdated and full of extremely bad coding practices and that's the reason I'm giving you -1, because your answer will probably encourage people who arrive here via google to use it, when they **should not**. We have PDO in this day and age which replaces the need for outdated `mysql_*` extension.

Comment: The reason I used mysql_* is because the OP is obviously unfamiliar with PDO and relatively new to PHP. He is looking for a way to split his code into classes and that is what I showed him using practices he is familiar with. That way he isn't too overwhelmed with having to figure out classes and PDO at the same time.

I even said at the end to use PDO, but at least this gives the OP a way to separate into classes and then can update to PDO by only having to change the Database class.

Comment: And that's what you shouldn't do, if you see someone going the wrong way then help them by showing the proper one, not further polluting already polluted topic. If you're willing to change your example to PDO, I'll gladly remove my downvote.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude towards you (gave you the upvote now), however please try to guide people to correct methods rather than fixing the code for them and let them run off with awful coding practices.

Comment: No problem. I do understand, I was just trying to answer the guy's question without confusing him too much with too many changes and best practices thrown at his face. But you are right - we don't want to reinforce bad practices by posting an answer using outdated code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below for the code example:

```
class SomeClass {

    protected $db = null;
    protected $table = 'blogdata';

    public function __construct()
    {
        // db connection options
        $driverOptions = array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => "SET NAMES 'utf8'",
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
        );

        // set new connection
        $this->db = PDO(
            "mysql:dbname=blogg1;host=localhost",
            'root', '', $driverOptions
        );
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        // prepare your data
        $title = $data["title"];
        $category = $data["category"];
        $content = $data ["content"];

        // prepare statement
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
            INSERT INTO {$this->table} (title , category , content) VALUES
            (:title, :category, :content);
        ");

        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();       
    }

    public function getRecords()
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
            SELECT * 
            FROM {$this->table} 
            ORDER BY id DESC
        ");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

And a usage example:

```
<?php

require_once('SomeClass.php');
$ent = new SomeClass();

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $ent->save($_POST);
} 
else {

    // get and output
    $records = $ent->getRecords();

    if (count($records) > 0) {
?>
<table>
    <?php
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            echo "<tr><td>{$record->title}</td><td>{$record->category}</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'>{$record->content}</td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```